# How is method local variable getting accessed in lambda function?

Tags: java, lambda

I am new to Lambda, in below code how a method variable (`personslist`) is accessible in lambda method?

Output code is whole list instead of just one person:

```
public class ApplicationL1 {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Person> personslist = new ArrayList<>();

        personslist.add(new Person("A", 10, Gender.Male));
        personslist.add(new Person("B", 16, Gender.Female));
        personslist.add(new Person("C", 18, Gender.Female));
        personslist.add(new Person("D", 31, Gender.Female));
        personslist.add(new Person("E", 12, Gender.Female));
        personslist.add(new Person("F", 9, Gender.Male));
        personslist.add(new Person("G", 40, Gender.Male));

        filterPerson(personslist, 
            personA -> personA.getGender() == Gender.Female && personA.getAge() > 30 && personA.getAge() < 40, 
            personB -> System.out.println(personslist.toString()));
    }

    private static void filterPerson(List<Person> personlist, Predicate<Person> tester, Consumer<Person> filtered) {
        for (Person person : personlist) {
            if (tester.test(person)) {
                filtered.accept(person);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not reason for you to expect `personslist.toString()` to print only a `Person` who passed the filter.

If you wish your code to print only the people matching the filter, you shouldn't print the entire list. Just print each `Person` who passed the filter :

```
filterPerson(personslist, 
        personA -> personA.getGender() == Gender.Female && personA.getAge() > 30 && personA.getAge() < 40, 
        personB -> System.out.println(personB));
```

`personslist` is accessible to the lambda expression since it is effectively final.